# How to hide the splash screen in verysilent mode setup of Inno Setup using ISSI?

Tags: inno-setup, splash-screen, pascalscript, silent, issi

I'm using ISSI (that is a 3rd party of Inno Setup) for the splash screen of my setup. But when I launch it in `/VERYSILENT` mode I still have the splash screen that it displayed.

I think the splash screen is displayed before the setup or something like that.

How to hide the splash screen please?

I'm using Jenkins to test the setup, so I must not have something that appears as a window or splash.

I searched all internet without finding an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not look like ISSI supports such customization. But you can hack it like this:

```pascal
[ISSI]
#define ISSI_SplashScreen_T "{code:GetSplashTime}"

[Code]

function GetSplashTime(Param: string): string;
begin
  if WizardSilent then Result := '0'
    else Result := '5';
end;

[ISSI]
```

---

Cleaner way would be to copy over the splash screen code from `_issi.isi` to your script.